# Qu'est-ce qui rime avec « cirque » ?

Tags: vocabulaire

Je m'en réfère à vous, puits de science de la langue française, puisque mon dictionnaire, Internet et ma propre connaissance m'ont laissé tombé.

Existe-t-il un mot de la langue française qui rime avec « cirque » ?

Question subsidiaire : s'il n'existe pas de rime, comment se fait-ce ? Je trouve ça étrange qu'un mot n'ait pas de rime, c'est à ma connaissance le seul cas.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Le [dictionnaire des rimes](http://dictionnaire-des-rimes.fr/rime-en-irque.html) ne nous donne... rien qui rime en -irque.

Un autre [dictionnaire de rime](http://www.dicocitations.com/dico-rime/25499/cirque.php#Rime), idem, pas de [rime riche](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rime#Richesse_des_rimes) avec cirque.

Il va falloir, j'en ai peur, te contenter de rimes un peu moins riches.

Cela n'est pas si rare qu'un mot n'ai pas de rime (dans les noms communs, avec des noms propres, c'est plus facile de trouver des rimes)

Voila une petite liste d'autres mots qui ne riment avec rien :

> *triomphe*, *quatorze*, *quinze*, *simple*, *pauvre*, *meurtre*,
>   *monstre*, *belge*, *goinfre*

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse complète. Diantre, je ne pensais pas qu'il y avait autant de mots sans rime en français !

Answer (score 14):

En un mot, il n'y a rien.

Mais avec un peu de licence poétique, on peut inventer un *cire-queue* par exemple.

Ou bien évoquer *Saint-Cyr, que* / l'on n'oserait comparer à un cirque.

Comment: C'est d'ailleurs du plus bel effet.

Comment: +1 pour l'idée (fameuse je trouve) avec Saint-Cyr. Ca m'évoque les rimes "à mot coupé" que Gainsbourg (par exemple, mais surement beaucoup d'autres) a beaucoup utilisé. Quelqu'un sait si ça a un nom ?

Comment: @RomainVALERI - Bobby Lapointe aussi était très fort sur ce genre de rimes.

Comment: Tout-à-fait. Nous avons les mêmes "maîtres".

Comment: On peut remonter à Brassens, avec l'exemple fameux de Tempête dans un bénitier :
_Ô Sainte-Marie Mèr'de.../Dieu dites à ces putains_
Les montagnes russes de l'anticléricalisme !

Answer (score 11):

Il n'y a aucun mot de la langue française qui rime avec "cirque", et ce n'est pas le seul cas. J'ai cherché récemment d'autres exemples de mots sans rime, et j'ai trouvé la liste suivante ([source](http://a3nm.net/blog/french_no_rhyme.html)) :

abrupt, ardre, aspre, baile, belge, birbe, bolge, bougre, bulbe, camphre, chanvre, chintz, chypre, clephte, cirque, crispent, curve, dextre, dioptre, dipneuste, disjonctent, distincte, divulgue, dogme, drachme, edelweiss, exècrent, fichtre, film, fougue, fourche, gaufre, genre, girofle, goinfre, golfe, humble, hurle, hydne, hymne, indemne, iodlent, jaspe, jouxte, jungle, larve, lorsque, mandorle, meurtre, monstre, moult, muscle, ogre, ourlent, pampre, pauvre, pentateuque, peuple, pourpre, putsch, quartz, quatorze, quelque, quinze, rostre, sanve, sarclent, sceptre, sépulcre, serpe, siècle, simple, sourdre, stagnent, sylphe, sylve, tertre, usurpe, veld, verste, vulve.

Comment: +1 pour le verbe *ardre* qui m'a fait un choc. Cela dit, jolie liste, merci.

Comment: *dextre* et *senestre*, sans être des rimes riches, sont tout à fait acceptables par le sifflement antérieur à la dernière syllabe ; *caroube* et (il) *radoube* sont riches - il y en a sûrement d'autres

Comment: @cl-r: Je suis d'accord pour caroube, merci beaucoup ! J'ai corrigé. Pour "dextre" et "sénestre", je croyais que le critère pour qu'une rime soit acceptable était que le dernier son vocalique et tous les sons consonantiques devaient coïncider exactement. Auriez-vous un exemple attesté chez un auteur classique, ou une référence sur la justification, qui confirmerait que c'est votre interprétation qui est correcte ? Merci !

Comment: La rime est acceptable, car il y continuité dans le sens des mots :
*dextre*, *senestre* et *ambidextre* ne concerne que  la latéralité du corps humain, quelque chose comme droite, gauche, les deux (mains, pieds, cotés du corps) – On peut toujours inventer : La muse contemplant sa main dextre/habile elle se coiffe de la senestre – Voilà une solution 'tirée par les cheveux', et je n'ai pas trouvé de rimes ‘ambidextres’

Comment: Je n'ai vraiment jamais entendu parler de rimes dont la validité dépendrait du sens... à défaut d'une référence pour justifier cette affirmation je ne pense pas pouvoir la considérer comme correcte.

Answer (score 3):

Si vous n'avez pas besoin d'une rime riche en 3 sons il y a des rimes en 2 sons :

> barque, orque, marque, …

Comment: Oui, c'est déjà beaucoup mieux que "crique".